# Combine two tables that have no common fields

Tags: sql-server, union

I want to learn how to combine two db tables which have no fields in common. I've checked UNION but MSDN says :

> The following are basic rules for combining the result sets of two queries by using UNION:
>
> 1. The number and the order of the columns must be the same in all queries.
> 2. The data types must be compatible.

But I have no fields in common at all. All I want is to combine them in one table like a view.

So what should I do?

Comment: for who can't think of a logical real world usage, imagine this: you have a table of gift coupons. you're making some manual corrections on the db, and you wish to reserve (set member IDs for) N of the coupons to N people who are in your query result. You can use cursors, or an application written in another language, but a clean sql with a CTE just fits the bill, without having you leave your SQL session. -and row numbers are the way to go

Comment: This question is not clear. "Combine" means nothing. [mre]

Comment: I've already posted a solution for a similar issue here. https://stackoverflow.com/a/71940218/6521046

Answer (score 139, accepted):

There are a number of ways to do this, depending on what you *really* want. With no common columns, you need to decide whether you want to introduce a common column or get the product.

Let's say you have the two tables:

```
parts:              custs:
+----+----------+   +-----+------+
| id | desc     |   |  id | name |
+----+----------+   +-----+------+
|  1 | Sprocket |   | 100 | Bob  |
|  2 | Flange   |   | 101 | Paul |
+----+----------+   +-----+------+
```

Forget the actual columns since you'd most likely *have* a customer/order/part relationship in this case; I've just used those columns to illustrate the ways to do it.

A cartesian product will match every row in the first table with every row in the second:

```
> select * from parts, custs;
      id desc     id  name
      -- ----     --- ----
      1  Sprocket 101 Bob
      1  Sprocket 102 Paul
      2  Flange   101 Bob
      2  Flange   102 Paul
```

That's probably not what you want since 1000 parts and 100 customers would result in 100,000 rows with lots of duplicated information.

Alternatively, you can use a union to just output the data, though not side-by-side (you'll need to make sure column types are compatible between the two selects, either by making the table columns compatible or coercing them in the select):

```
> select id as pid, desc, null as cid, null as name from parts
  union
  select null as pid, null as desc, id as cid, name from custs;
    pid desc     cid name
    --- ----     --- ----
                 101 Bob 
                 102 Paul
    1   Sprocket
    2   Flange
```

In some databases, you can use a rowid/rownum column or pseudo-column to match records side-by-side, such as:

```
id desc     id  name
-- ----     --- ----
1  Sprocket 101 Bob
2  Flange   101 Bob
```

The code would be something like:

```
select a.id, a.desc, b.id, b.name
from parts a, custs b
where a.rownum = b.rownum;
```

It's still *like* a cartesian product but the `where` clause limits how the rows are combined to form the results (so not a cartesian product at all, really).

I haven't tested that SQL for this since it's one of the limitations of my DBMS of choice, and rightly so, I don't believe it's ever needed in a properly thought-out schema. Since SQL doesn't guarantee the order in which it produces data, the matching can change every time you do the query unless you have a *specific* relationship or `order by` clause.

I think the ideal thing to do would be to add a column to both tables specifying what the relationship is. If there's no real relationship, then you probably have no business in trying to put them side-by-side with SQL.

If you just want them displayed side-by-side in a report or on a web page (two examples), the right tool to do that is whatever generates your report or web page, coupled with two *independent* SQL queries to get the two unrelated tables. For example, a two-column grid in BIRT (or Crystal or Jasper) each with a separate data table, or a HTML two column table (or CSS) each with a separate data table.

Comment: Thanks,that is pretty nice answer and show me better way to achieve the solution.

Comment: Is there a rownum or rowid in MySQL?

Comment: This is my fav mysql answer!

Comment: "That's probably not what you want" - but it is... how do you achieve this?

Comment: @pstanton, how you achieve that is in the code block immediately before that paragraph, the `select * from parts, custs`.

Comment: I've already posted a better solution for similar issue here. https://stackoverflow.com/a/71940218/6521046

Answer (score 30):

This is a very strange request, and almost certainly something you'd never want to do in a real-world application, but from a purely academic standpoint it's an interesting challenge. With SQL Server 2005 you could use common table expressions and the row_number() functions and join on that:

```
with OrderedFoos as (
    select row_number() over (order by FooName) RowNum, *
    from Foos (nolock)
),
OrderedBars as (
    select row_number() over (order by BarName) RowNum, *
    from Bars (nolock)
)
select * 
from OrderedFoos f
    full outer join OrderedBars u on u.RowNum = f.RowNum
```

This works, but it's supremely silly and I offer it only as a "community wiki" answer because I really wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: +1 yeah row numbers are the way to go, but I'd use inner joins. for a real world usage please see my comment on the question -)

Comment: This is what I needed! I was tasked with implementing a FK constraint between two tables whose only common field was the id on a one-many relationship eg. TblA has 5 TblB's and 5 TblC's but business logic changes mean every TblC now needs a 1-1 relationship to a TblB. I have to retroactively populate this relationship so the field can be made unique and non-nullable moving forward. This provided a way for me to populate that for historical data already in the system

Comment: There **is** a usage, for the scenario where you _want to_ compare two tables, with   legacy data and _new_ data,[your application db depends on some other company db] where some _master minded_ **_people_** _`came`_, and changed the master data ! -- and when you want to `see` the _differences_ rather than utilising `not in` and `except` thing -- nice alternative for me though :)

Comment: This worked perfectly for me without worrying about duplicate data. I have a scenario where I wanted to load some config data from a couple of tables( small sized) once from my class rather than making call  to DB 2 times.  With this I can just load both tables data at once and use it in my client library.

Answer (score 11):

```
SELECT *
FROM table1, table2
```

This will join every row in table1 with table2 (the Cartesian product) returning all columns.

Comment: What if they are different database tables ? Thanks.

Comment: This will cause a cross-join, which doesn't seem to be what he's looking for.

Comment: This is useful in a particular case. If I have to make three trips to a database where each query will return a single row and each query incurs network delay time, then I can combine the three queries into one query like
select * 
from (select x from tab1 where condition1), select y from tab2 where condition2), (select z from tab3 where condition3);

Answer (score 5):

```
select 
    status_id, 
    status, 
    null as path, 
    null as Description 
from 
    zmw_t_status

union
select 
    null, 
    null, 
    path as cid, 
    Description from zmw_t_path;
```

Comment: it will ignore one of those field names, I think you just need to put field name aliases on the last union

Comment: This came in handy - it's efficient

Answer (score 5):

try:

```
select * from table 1 left join table2 as t on 1 = 1;
```

This will bring all the columns from both the table.

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which may provide some immediate help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its educational value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with similar, but not identical, questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: Can you explain how that is different from cross join without on?

Answer (score 3):

If the tables have no common fields then there is no way to combine the data in any meaningful view. You would more likely end up with a view that contains duplicated data from both tables.

Answer (score 2):

To get a meaningful/useful view of the two tables, you normally need to determine an identifying field from each table that can then be used in the ON clause in a JOIN.

THen in your view:

```
SELECT T1.*, T2.* FROM T1 JOIN T2 ON T1.IDFIELD1 = T2.IDFIELD2
```

You mention no fields are "common", but although the identifying fields may not have the same name or even be the same data type, you could use the convert / cast functions to join them in some way.

Comment: Even if there aren't any directly shared fields, there must be some relationship between the tables for the view to be meaningful. That relationship needs to be captured in the ON clause.

Answer (score 2):

why don't you use simple approach

```
    SELECT distinct *
    FROM 
    SUPPLIER full join 
    CUSTOMER on (
        CUSTOMER.OID = SUPPLIER.OID
    )
```

It gives you all columns from both tables and returns all records from customer and supplier if Customer has 3 records and supplier has 2 then supplier'll show NULL in all columns

Answer (score 2):

```
Select 
DISTINCT  t1.col,t2col
From table1 t1, table2 t2

OR

Select 
DISTINCT  t1.col,t2col
From table1 t1 
cross JOIN  table2 t2
```

if its hug data , its take long time ..

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT t1.col table1col, t2.col table2col
FROM table1 t1 
JOIN table2 t2 on t1.table1Id = x and t2.table2Id = y
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing
additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ it answers
the question would significantly improve its long-term
value.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation.

Answer (score 1):

**Joining Non-Related Tables**

[image]

***Demo SQL Script***

```
IF OBJECT_ID('Tempdb..#T1') IS NOT NULL  DROP TABLE #T1;

CREATE TABLE #T1 (T1_Name VARCHAR(75));

INSERT INTO #T1 (T1_Name) VALUES ('Animal'),('Bat'),('Cat'),('Duet');

SELECT * FROM #T1;

IF OBJECT_ID('Tempdb..#T2') IS NOT NULL  DROP TABLE #T2;

CREATE TABLE #T2 (T2_Class VARCHAR(10));

INSERT INTO #T2 (T2_Class) VALUES ('Z'),('T'),('H'); 

SELECT * FROM #T2;
```

To Join Non-Related Tables , we are going to introduce one common joining column of Serial Numbers like below.

**SQL Script**

```
SELECT T1.T1_Name,ISNULL(T2.T2_Class,'') AS T2_Class FROM
( SELECT T1_Name,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS S_NO FROM #T1) T1
LEFT JOIN
( SELECT T2_Class,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS S_NO FROM #T2) T2
ON t1.S_NO=T2.S_NO;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from this_table;

select distinct person from this_table

union select address as location from that_table 

drop wrong_table from this_database;
```

Answer (score 0):

Very hard when you have to do this with three select statments

I tried all proposed techniques up there but it's in-vain

Please see below script. please advice if you have alternative solution

```
   select distinct x.best_Achiver_ever,y.Today_best_Achiver ,z.Most_Violator from 

    (SELECT  Top(4) ROW_NUMBER() over (order by tl.username)  AS conj, tl. 
     [username] + '-->' + str(count(*)) as best_Achiver_ever 
    FROM[TiketFollowup].[dbo].N_FCR_Tikect_Log_Archive tl
     group by tl.username
     order by count(*) desc) x
      left outer join 

(SELECT 
Top(4) ROW_NUMBER() over (order by tl.username)  as conj, tl.[username] + '-->' + str(count(*)) as Today_best_Achiver
FROM[TiketFollowup].[dbo].[N_FCR_Tikect_Log] tl
where convert(date, tl.stamp, 121) = convert(date,GETDATE(),121)
group by tl.username
order by count(*) desc) y 
on x.conj=y.conj

 left outer join 

(
select  ROW_NUMBER() over (order by count(*)) as conj,username+ '--> ' + str( count(dbo.IsViolated(stamp))) as Most_Violator from N_FCR_Ticket
where dbo.IsViolated(stamp) = 'violated' and  convert(date,stamp, 121) < convert(date,GETDATE(),121)
group by username
order by count(*) desc) z
on x.conj = z.conj
```

Answer (score -2):

Please try this query:

Combine two tables that have no common columns:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table1 

UNION 

SELECT * 
FROM table2  
ORDER BY orderby ASC
```

Comment: This only works when both tables have an equal number of expressions

Comment: Well it is nearly the same as the excepted answer, in the accepted answer they added 'empty' columns to by pass this problem