# How to merge 2 completely different tables?

Tags: sql, postgresql, merge

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Combine two tables that have no common fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1198124/combine-two-tables-that-have-no-common-fields)

I'm looking at merging 2 tables, that have nothing in common (No columns, No IDs) into 1 single table.
it's for reporting purposes. I need to just grab all the columns in table 1 and all the columns in table 2 and put them into 1 table, so the data doesn't change, it's just that instead of being in 2 tables they'll be into 1.

Example

Table1: `KeyboardID, Computermodel, factory`

Table2: `MouseID, Speakers, Circuitboard`

New table of those 2 combined: `KeyboardID, Computermodel, factory, MouseID, Speakers, Circuitboard`

Update: I'm gonna clarify myself:

Here's my situation View1: `StarID, Planet, Sun` and then `View2: StarID, Planet, Sun` As you can see they have the exact same column names; Here's how I'm expecting my 3rd view to look like:

`StarID, Planet, Planet2, Sun, Sun2`

I would not mind having the 3rd view look like this:

`StarID, StarID2, Planet, Planet2, Sun, Sun2`

here's the catch, they do not relate at all, you're probably thinking "Join them on `StarID`" unfortunately I cant as technically I need `StarID` from View1 to be appended to `StarID` on View2 or have them in completely separate columns (this is because there's no relationship in the data) to complicate things, `StarID` may not be unique (I'm not sure if there's uniqueness constraints to views I'm fairly new to postgres)

Comment: the number of rows in both tables is equal?

Comment: are the two tables related in any way whatsoever?

Comment: No they aren't related in anyway. And yes they happen to be the same number of columns, just a coincidence.

Comment: If it's "for reporting purposes", do you really want a new table?  Or do you want a view/query?

Comment: You're right it's technically a View, but I'm at the point where I'll settle for anything.

Comment: So, wait - there's no relation at all between the data?  You just want a cross join, i.e. Every entry in View1 matched with Every entry in view 2?

Comment: There's no relation to the data, that's why I want to keep a separation by adding a number "2" to the columns coming from View2

Comment: I though as soon as I gave a checkmark it died out, plus the answers I got where really helpful doing what I had asked, it's only after I kept finding out what Ive really been trying to do. Thanks for the advice, I just went ahead and edited that post.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [full outer join](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.0/static/queries-table-expressions.html):

> FULL OUTER JOIN
>
> First, an inner join is performed. Then, for each row
>   in T1 that does not satisfy the join condition with any row in T2, a
>   joined row is added with null values in columns of T2. Also, for each
>   row of T2 that does not satisfy the join condition with any row in T1,
>   a joined row with null values in the columns of T1 is added.

So your query would be something like:

```
select
  *          -- or explicitly list column names
from
  <table1>
full outer join
  <table2> on <some join condition>
```

Note that the join condition should always be false.  The result will be something like:

```
KeyboardID   Computermodel    factory      MouseID     Speakers     Circuitboard
1            something        something3   (null)      (null)       (null)       
2            something2       something4   (null)      (null)       (null)       
(null)       (null)           (null)        17         something5   something8
(null)       (null)           (null)        22         something6   something7
```

Notice that the columns from the "other" table are always null, and that the number of rows is (number of rows in Table1) + (number of rows in Table2).

---

Note:  I'm not a PostGresQL expert, so I didn't have a chance to test this query.

Comment: I doubt that's what he wants.

Comment: @aF. -- on the contrary, it seems to be exactly what he wants.

Comment: doesn't he want on the same row?

Comment: How can I do a JOIN if they don't connect on any level?

Comment: @user1183513 -- I've updated my answer to show the query and the expected results.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds as if you're trying to hack together a two-up listing, where the two sides don't actually have anything to do with each other.

You can synthesize a key by using row_number(). I don't have Postgres here, but something like this might work:

```
SELECT * FROM 
    (SELECT KeyboardID, Computermodel, factory, row_number() as num FROM Table1) AS X
FULL OUTER JOIN 
    (SELECT MouseID, Speakers, Circuitboard, row_number() as num FROM Table2) AS Y
ON x.num = y.num
```

It arbitrarily matches rows from the two tables, with no duplicates.

By creating a synthetic 'key', you don't get all those "(null)" values.

Comment: What if they have different number of rows?

Comment: @MattFenwick: changed it to `FULL OUTER JOIN` :)

Comment: ERROR:  function row_number() does not exist
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You may need to add explicit type casts.

Comment: @user1183513: I'm going by the docs at http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/interactive/functions-window.html

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this answer.   paxdiablo gave probably the clearest and most complete explanation of your options for accomplishing this.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/1198234/1042438

Comment: Seems like the end all answer is that you can't do it if there's no relation :/

Comment: There are a number of ways to do it.  The question is will they fit in to what your desired end result is.

Answer (score -1):

INSERT INTO table3 (KeyboardID, Computermodel, factory)
  SELECT *
  FROM table1;

INSERT INTO table3 (MouseID, Speakers, Circuitboard)
  SELECT *
  FROM table2;

You can insert data sing these commands, you need to create table dynamically as well?

Comment: I considered it but it's for reporting purposes and I need it to be a query that gives results right off the bat.