# MSQL creating a table which automatically updates with data from other tables

Tags: mysql

I have two tables:

Table1 - Sales
id, Timestamp, Notes, CSR, Date, ExistingCustomer, PubCode, Price, Pub, Expiry, Size, KeyCode, UpSell, CustName, CustAddress, CustCity, CustState, CustPostal, CustCountry, CustPhone, CustEmail, CustCardName, CustCardNumber, CustCardType, CustCardExpiry, CustCardCode

Table2 - Refunds
id,Timestamp,CSR,Date,OrderId,Refunded,Saved,Publication

Basically, I want to create a table (MySQL) which will have some columns that are the same between the two tables and which will update automatically with the values from these two columns.

ie. Table3
Timestamp, CSR, Date, Publication

And this table would automatically update whenever a new record is posted into either of the other two tables, so it would essentially be a merged table.

Because there's nothing to join these two tables, I don't think the JOIN function would work here. Is there anyway I can do this?

Comment: You can create a View. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1198124/combine-two-tables-that-have-no-common-fields

Answer (score 0):

You can use an trigger which actives on insert on both tables to make it automatically update.

As for combining tables with no common tables, view [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1198124/combine-two-tables-that-have-no-common-fields) question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a stored procedure and a trigger on insert/update of the non merged table

Answer (score 0):

There's got to be some way to join it, and in fact you mention Timestamp, CSR, Date, Publication.

You could join on them in a  view. You could add table three and then add triggers though that would be an awful mess.

Why do you want to denormalise in this way?

How about Table3 is a unique key to use as a surrogate, and your 4 join fields, and then you take those out of Table 1 and 2 and replace them with the key the suurrogate key in table 3.

Then it'sa  simple join query and no data duplication.