# Two tables concatenation

Tags: sql, ms-access

I've stuck with my homework on Data Bases for a two days...

I'm working in MS Access, and I have two tables R and S, with the same number of rows. They don't have any relationship.
Let's say table R has only two columns (named `A, B)`, and so the table S (named `B, C).`

In the table R there is only three records: `(a1,b1), (a1,b2), (a2,b1)`

In the table S there is only three records: `(b1,c1), (b1,c3), (b2,c2)`

I need to concatenate these two tables into one, so the new table will have four columns (RA, RB, SB, SC) and will have the next records:

```
(a1,b1,b1,c1),  
(a1,b2,b1,c3),  
(a2,b1,b2,c2)
```

That's all... The question is: How do I accomplish this with SQL??

Comment: How are `R` and `S` related to each other? I don't see foreign keys.

Comment: They're not related to each other. This is just two tables...

Comment: If they bear no relation to each other, why do this? Why not select one table then the other?

Comment: I need just to implement concatenation operation as: T = R + S

Comment: It's just a college task =)  I just stuck with that question about for a two days, and can't find solution...

Comment: Please read [How to ask and answer homework questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-to-ask-and-answer-homework-questions).

Comment: I'm using MS Access (now edited in my question)

Answer (score 3):

Very contrived, but runs in MS Access.

```
SELECT x.f0, x.F1, y.F0, y.F1
FROM (
     SELECT DISTINCT r.F0, r.F1, 
         (select count(*) 
         from r a 
         where a.f0+a.f1<=r.f0+r.f1) AS Expr1
      FROM r)  AS x 
INNER JOIN (
     SELECT DISTINCT s.F0, s.F1, 
        (select count(*) 
         from s a 
         where a.f0+a.f1<=s.f0+s.f1) AS Expr1
     FROM s)  AS y 
ON x.Expr1 = y.Expr1;
```

**Table S**

```
F0  F1 <-- Field names
b1  c1
b1  c3
b2  c2
```

**Table R**

```
F0  F1 <-- Field names
a1  b2
a2  b1
a1  b1
```

**Query result**

```
x.F0    x.F1    y.F0    y.F1
a1      b1      b1      c1
a1      b2      b1      c3
a2      b1      b2      c2
```

Comment: That is because you have not given any field names, so I have use default fields f0 and f1.

Comment: wooops, I called the columns "rows" on auto in my question... But anyway, I tried to substitute the real column names. And as a result I've got the same dialog windows... Strange... BTW, what does "a.f0+a.f1"  means?

Comment: `a` is the alias of the table in the subquery to allow comparison of field `f0 & f1` ( or `f0+f1`) with the outer query.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like what you want to do is to JOIN the two tables by row number. Check out [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1198124/combine-two-tables-that-have-no-common-fields)

For an example of how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm with Chase on this one, it seems like you want to do an SQL join like:

```
SELECT *
FROM TableR R, TableS S
WHERE R.id=S.id;
```

**What this is saying is in plain english**: **Select** all the columns/rows **from** both `Table R` and `Table S` **where** the primary key `ID` in `Table R` equals the same primary key `ID` value in `Table S`

Not sure which database you are using, but here's a bit [more information](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html).

Comment: I understand the logic behind your answer... But my problem is that I don't have an ID field in my tables... and like I already said in my comment above - These tables don't have any relationship...

Comment: I think I had misunderstood your question. Why dont you make a PK on each and do a join of the results, then just create a new table populating those results? I think that'd be the quickest fix.

Comment: Because it isn't given in our HomeWork question... With a PK I wasn't ask a question here after 2 days of screwing my brain))

Answer (score 0):

OK, my answer is very different from the others.

You stated that there's no relation between the 2 tables. Everyone else is trying to make a relation between R.B & S.B, but you said there is no relation.

So, if there's no relation, then you don't put one in. So what you'll get is:
SELECT R.*, S.*
FROM R,S

The results will be every column from both tables and the rows returned will equal the rows from R times the rows from S. In your example above, you'll get 9 records back.