# getting different column names from 2 tables in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I have Item and Sales tables with different columns like,

Item

```
ItemName                        
Itemcost                       
ItemQty
```

Sales

```
 SalesName     
 SalesDate  
 SalesQty
```

In the above tables there is not common column,but i need to get output as

```
ItemName,ItemCost,SalesName,SalesDate.
```

I tried with union,

```
select ItemName,ItemCost from Item
union     
select SalesName,SalesDate from Sales
```

but am getting only 1 table columns like ItemName,ItemCost

Please help me on this issue

Thanks In Advance

Venkat.

Comment: Looks like a duplicate - see [Combine two tables that have no common fields](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1198124/combine-two-tables-that-have-no-common-fields/1198234#1198234) for an answer.

Comment: Hi,

You want data from both the table.Please clarify it.I guess there is common column, U should use join,Instead of UNION

Comment: You really should specify how you expect your data to look in the end. The answers below are Cartesian products, which are almost always something to avoid.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use below sql query :

```
select i.ItemName, i.ItemCost, s.SalesName, s.SalesDate 
from Item as i, Sales as s;
```

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was discontinued with the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**20 years** ago!). ***Please*** stop using it

Answer (score 1):

Use the below query :

This will join every row in table1 with table2 (the Cartesian product) returning all columns.

```
Select im.ItemName, im.ItemCost, sl.SalesName,sl.SalesDate from Item as im, Sales as sl;
```

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was discontinued with the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**20 years** ago!). ***Please*** stop using it