# Combine two tables with no relationship between them

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have two table with single column. i.e Type and URL these are as

```
items
-----
image
image
image
video

items
-----
http://photo.com/some.jpg
http://photo.com/some1.jpg
http://photo.com/some2.jpg
http://video.com/some.avi
```

I want result as

```
    Type                     URL
    -----------------------------
    image                    http://photo.com/some.jpg
    image                    http://photo.com/some1.jpg
    image                    http://photo.com/some2.jpg
    video                    http://video.com/some.avi
```

how can i get result here type and url table have no primery key column

Comment: How would you possibly relate them if they don't share anything? You need to redesign your tables to have id or make one table.

Comment: Otherwise, you can possibly regexp to define file type...

Comment: @sashkello first item of Type table is Related to first item of URL table and so on.

Comment: Create  foreign-key and id. then it will be easier..

Comment: @Fasilkk item and url table is dynamically generated table so i need solution for that

Comment: Same question answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1198124/combine-two-tables-that-have-no-common-fields

Comment: @IlyaKlementiev in my case there is no id for on condition in join

Comment: @manoj : Is my solution Ok for you? If yes then Accept as Answer.

Comment: Change the way this is generated. Consider the possiblity to make one table out of this, or add keys. Just because something is generated, doesn't mean you can't change it.

Comment: @RomsJain i appreciate your answer but it give incorrect result http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/789e1/1

Comment: @manoj : Now check my answer again or Check it out [Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/789e1/11)

Comment: @RomsJain - Tables have no inherent order. You cannot rely on `ORDER BY (SELECT 0)` to do anything deterministic.

Comment: @MartinSmith then suggest me what to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can Find you solution [Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/789e1/11)

Below is the Detail

```
CREATE TABLE T1 (
    items VARCHAR(10)
)
CREATE TABLE T2 (
    items VARCHAR(100)
)
INSERT INTO T1
VALUES ('image'),('image'),('image'),('video')

INSERT INTO T2
VALUES ('http://photo.com/some.jpg'),('http://photo.com/some1.jpg'),('http://photo.com/some2.jpg'),('http://video.com/some.avi')


select TT1.t1_items as Type,TT2.t2_items as URL from 
(select items t1_items,row_number() over(order by (SELECT 0)) as t1r from t1) as TT1,
(select items t2_items,row_number() over(order by (SELECT 0)) as t2r from t2) as TT2
where TT1.t1r = TT2.t2r
```

Comment: This is only correct if the intention is to join both by their respective index in alphabetical order. The OP should add an `id` field for joining or just use one table as @sashkello already said.

Comment: @MartinSmith is wright , if i place video in 2nd row of type table then it give error result