# Combining two distinct Oracle queries

Tags: sql, oracle

So I have two queries

```
SELECT DISTINCT ReservationGroupName FROM EventDataTable
```

and

```
SELECT DISTINCT BookingEventType FROM EventDataTable
```

I'm making a form that lets you filter by one or both of these, so I need to print out each distinct result from each in a select dropdown.

I tried a UNION and a UNION ALL, but I just get an array of the results of ReservationGroupName, that **also contained** the results of BookingEventType.
There should be 540 results from ReservationGroupName, and 63 from BookingEventType, and that returns an array called ReservationGroupName with 603 elements. My problem is that I need to differentiate between the results

It would be possible to just do two queries seperately, but it seemed like I should be able to combine it, but a few hours of looking at old forums has just left me confused.

Current code:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ReservationGroupName AS \"group\", '' AS \"type\" FROM EventDataTable
    UNION
SELECT DISTINCT BookingEventType AS \"type\", '' AS \"group\" FROM EventDataTable
```

Returns a ReservationGroupName array with all of the data, but also an array of the same length populated by null values called EventDataTable.

Comment: You may find this answer helps you:

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1198124/combine-two-tables-that-have-no-common-fields][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1198124/combine-two-tables-that-have-no-common-fields

Comment: Hm. That did help, but I'm getting an array of null values for the types. I'll modify my question with the new code, as it looks like the way to go.

Comment: Why not use 2 queries? It seems the most sane approach.

Comment: @ypercube Mostly because it seemed like an interesting query, and I wanted to get better at SQL joins, as that was how I assumed I would do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may sound dumb, but the UNION may be relying on the field names and giving you a resultset that has a bunch of empty strings in the field you are attaching to the dropdown. Try something like this...

```
SELECT DISTINCT ReservationGroupName AS \"entry\", 'GroupName' AS \"type\" FROM EventDataTable
    UNION
SELECT DISTINCT BookingEventType AS \"entry\", 'EventType' AS \"type\" FROM EventDataTable
```

Comment: You should use UNION ALL instead of UNION here..  UNION does the extra step of removing duplicates.  Your DISTINCT in each select will ensure you don't have duplicates within the select, and the hard-coded types make it so you can't have duplicates between the 2 sets, so the extra step of the UNION is not needed.

Answer (score 0):

The UNION should work. Please find below the tables I created and I get the distinct values from both columns. Hope your design is same as below.

create table EventDataTable
(
ReservationGroupName VARCHAR2(20)
,BookingEventType VARCHAR2(20)
);

insert into EventDataTable values ('EMP','S');

insert into EventDataTable values ('ABC','T');

SELECT DISTINCT ReservationGroupName FROM EventDataTable
union
SELECT DISTINCT BookingEventType FROM EventDataTable;

DIS_VAL

ABC
EMP
S
T

Comment: That just returns an array labled ReservationGroupName, but it contains the elements from both ReservationGroupName and from BookingEventType. Didn't know it was doing that before, modifying the question to point that out.