# Need to query two tables in ASP.NET to fill ajax AutoCompleteExtender

Tags: asp.net, sql

Okay, I am trying to fill my ajax auto complete with values from 2 tables. The two tables don't have any matches. I just need to query both.

This is what i have working for one table [JD]. Just need to add the table [IH] with the same column OEMSubNumber

```
<System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod(), _
System.Web.Services.WebMethod()> _
    Public Shared Function SearchNumbers(ByVal prefixText As String, ByVal count As Integer) As List(Of String)
        'Declaring Connection String
        Dim sqlConnectionString As String
        sqlConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("baminterchangerConnectionString").ConnectionString
        Dim sqlConnection As New SqlConnection(sqlConnectionString)

        Dim cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand
        cmd.CommandText = "select OEMSubNumber from JD where" & _
            " OEMSubNumber like @SearchText + '%'"
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SearchText", prefixText)
        cmd.Connection = sqlConnection
        sqlConnection.Open()
        Dim customers As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)
        Dim sdr As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader
        While sdr.Read
            customers.Add(sdr("OEMSubNumber").ToString)
        End While
        sqlConnection.Close()

        Return customers
    End Function
```

I read the posted link below and tried out the UNION and select * but still not getting this.

Here's and example

```
JD:                            IH:
+--------------+----------+   +--------------+----------+
| OEMSubNumber |  Desc    |   | OEMSubNumber |  Desc    | 
+--------------+----------+   +--------------+----------+  
|     R1245    | Sprocket |   |    1354C1    |  Gasket  | 
|     L6125    | Flange   |   |    1542A2    |  Pulley  |
+--------------+----------+   +--------------+----------+
```

I need the query to join the tables like so

```
+--------------+
| OEMSubNumber |
+--------------+ 
|     R1245    |
|     L6125    |
|    1354C1    |
|    1542A2    |
+--------------+
```

This way i can use my @SearchText to find matches for my auto complete.

Comment: I'm not sure what the question is.

Comment: The current code show the query to JD table. I need to query both JD and IH tables in column OEMSubNumber

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/1198234/242 for techniques on combining two tables that don't have common fields.

Comment: updated question with more details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't do a `select *` since you only need one field. But do use `union`. Modify your command as

```
cmd.CommandText = "select OEMSubNumber from JD where OEMSubNumber like @SearchText + '%'"
cmd.CommandText &= " union "
cmd.CommandText &= "select OEMSubNumber from IH where OEMSubNumber like @SearchText + '%'"
```