# Taking 2 columns of data from unrelated table

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I required to join 2 columns of data from 2 different tables with no common field. I've tried multiple methods but all of them are not my desired output

**Table 1**

```
+-------+--------+  
| Height| weight | 
+----+-----------+ 
|  154  | 90lbs  | 
|  185  | 152lbs |
|  174  | 132lbs |
+----+-----------+
```

**Table 2**

```
+-------+--------+  
| Age   | Illness| 
+----+-----------+ 
|  70   |   HA   | 
|  85   |   CD   |
+----+-----------+
```

**Desired Output**

```
+-------+--------+  
| Height| Age    | 
+----+-----------+ 
|  154  | 70     | 
|  185  | 85     |
|  174  |        |
+----+-----------+
```

All this are just sample codes. Yes, the desired output is kind of meaningless but is there anyway I can get this output? I'm using SQL developer.

Comment: But why? How can we know 185 and 85 should be in the same row?

Comment: @jarlh that was what I am tasked to. There isn't any justification it should be same row, but the data just has to be side by side, without duplication.

Comment: I'd do it in the above layer... (Or in a stored procedure.)

Answer (score 1):

I am unable to comment (as I need 50 rep), so I am posting it here.
You could use join operators.
There is a one similar question here. There are some interesting answers to it. Check them out below.
[Combine two tables that have no common fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1198124/combine-two-tables-that-have-no-common-fields)

Comment: Its not working for my desired result. The rownum gives me error.