# MySQL:Merge Two tables some columns are different

Tags: mysql, database, sqlite

i want to merge two sql tables requirements are

- game_data1 columns : install_date, source, installs, Spending, CPI
- game_data2 columns : install_date, purchase_date, source, revenue
- merged table(want like this) : install_date, source, installs,  Spending, CPI, purchase_date, revenue

i already read other SO answers like[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35292522/merge-two-tables-with-different-columns-mysql), So by reading these type of  answers i made a query which is

```
SELECT s.install_date, s.source, s.installs, s.Spending, s.CPI, r.install_date, r.purchase_date, r.source, r.revenue 

FROM game_data as s

JOIN game_data2 as r ON r.install_date = s.install_date AND r.source = s.source
```

it should make one install_date column and one source column but its making two seperate column i dont know whats wrong in this

> game_data1(table1 which i want to merge)

[image]

> game_data2(table2 which i want to merge)

[image]

i have already wrote a function to change the date format so dont mind the date format

> Result

```
+--------------+----------+----------+----------+----------+--------------+---------------+----------+---------+
| install_date | source   | installs | Spending | CPI      | install_date | purchase_date | source   | revenue |
+--------------+----------+----------+----------+----------+--------------+---------------+----------+---------+
| 2015-03-01   | facebook |    10000 |     6000 |      0.6 | 2015-03-01   | 2015-03-01    | facebook |     600 |
| 2015-03-01   | facebook |    10000 |     6000 |      0.6 | 2015-03-01   | 2015-03-01    | facebook |     600 |
| 2015-03-01   | facebook |    10000 |     6000 |      0.6 | 2015-03-01   | 2015-03-02    | facebook |     550 |
| 2015-03-01   | facebook |    10000 |     6000 |      0.6 | 2015-03-01   | 2015-03-02    | facebook |     550 |
| 2015-03-01   | facebook |    10000 |     6000 |      0.6 | 2015-03-01   | 2015-03-03    | facebook |     500 |
| 2015-03-01   | facebook |    10000 |     6000 |      0.6 | 2015-03-01   | 2015-03-03    | facebook |     500 |
| 2015-03-01   | facebook |    10000 |     6000 |      0.6 | 2015-03-01   | 2015-03-04    | facebook |     450 |
```

i want to merge these table as it is but i want install_date and source should be one column not two seperate columns

if somebody wants to take help i find it useful to take help but couldnt understand it properly: [Link](https://www.dummies.com/programming/databases/combine-information-from-multiple-mysql-tables-with-join/)

any help would be appreciated

Comment: This is tagged MySQL and sqlite. Which one are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you only need to specify `install_date` and `source` once in the query

```
SELECT 
    s.install_date,
    s.source,
    s.installs,
    s.Spending,
    s.CPI,
    r.purchase_date,
    r.revenue
FROM
    game_data AS s
        JOIN
    game_data2 AS r ON r.install_date = s.install_date
        AND r.source = s.source;
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT s.install_date, s.source, s.installs, s.Spending, s.CPI, r.purchase_date, r.source, r.revenue

FROM game_data as s

INNER JOIN game_data2 as r ON r.install_date = s.install_date AND r.source = s.source

Comment: yeah it is making one install_date but still showing two source columns