# Select from two tables as one table

Tags: sql-server

I don't know if it is possible or not. If possible, please help me to resolve this.

I have two tables, **table1** and **table2**

```
Table1                                     Table2

CashReceivedFrom     Amount               CashPaidOutto      Amount        
x                    100                   A                     300   
Y                    200                   B                     400 
z                    250 
xy                   300
```

There is no relation between table1 and table2. I want to execute a query so that my output looks like this:

**Output table**

```
CashReceivedFrom     Amount               CashPaidOutto      Amount        
    x                    100                   A               300   
    Y                    200                   B               400 
    z                    250 
    xy                   300
```

I want to use it for a daily cash reprt

Comment: Why? What are you trying to achieve with this?

Comment: just do the formatting on the UI, why do you need to have `x` rows with unrelated `y` rows and lots of null data from your db?

Comment: I have a situation where i want to display daily cash flow. **Cash received** and **cash paid out** i have these two tables the first table i store it cash received and the second table cash paid out. so i want to execute a query so that my output looks like that way:

Comment: Check this question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1198124/combine-two-tables-that-have-no-common-fields

Comment: @SharmaHussein because you need to display something a certain way, does not mean you need to return the data ***in that exact format***.  It doesn't really make sense too.  It's like formatting your dates on the DB instead of the UI, sure you ***can*** but you lose out on a lot by doing so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This gives you what you want.

```
CREATE TABLE #TMP1 (ID INT,Amnt INT)
CREATE TABLE #TMP2 (ID INT,Amnt INT)

INSERT INTO #TMP1 VALUES
(1,100)
,(2,130)
,(3,10)
,(4,160)

INSERT INTO #TMP2 VALUES
(76,1024)
,(78,134)

;WITH cteA
    AS
    (
    SELECT *
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ID) AS Pos
    FROM #TMP1
    )
,cteB
    AS
    (
    SELECT *
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ID) AS Pos
    FROM #TMP2
    )
SELECT
    A.ID
    ,A.Amnt
    ,B.ID
    ,B.Amnt
FROM
    cteA A
        LEFT JOIN cteB  B
            ON
            A.Pos = B.Pos
```

Comment: thnx alotttt @pacreely it fixed my issue .thnx alot. :)

Comment: In my solution I'm ordering by ID. I recommend that in your solution you replace it with the key field in your clustered index. It will improve performance.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below statement. I dont know why you need data with Null. But below snippet might be help you.

```
   SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) 
  AS SNO, CASHRECIEVEDFROM, AMOUNT FROM TABLE1
  ) AS A
  FULL OUTER JOIN
   SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) 
  AS SNO, CASHPAIDTO, AMOUNT FROM TABLE2
  ) AS B ON A.SNO = B.SNO
```