# SELECT column FROM 2 tables Then Output In New table In 2 column

Tags: php, mysql

Say there are 2 tables with:

```
no key ref to each other
different number of rows

table1:
id   item
a    Apple
b    Pear

table2
no   student
I    John
II   Sara
III  Pete
```

Is it possible to combine:

```
SELECT item FROM table1
SELECT student FROM table2
```

Then PHP output table3 like this?

```
table3
ITEM       Student
Apple      John
Pear       Sara
           Pete
```

ITEM and Student are totally independent of each other. I just want to list them side by side. (Which means ITEM that same row with Pete will have no value).
Need some expert view. Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Inner-join with 3 tables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10195451/sql-inner-join-with-3-tables)

Comment: You would at least need to define which student got which item. Then you could make an [SQL Join](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp).

Comment: ITEM and Student are totally independent of each other. I just want to list them side by side in new table.

Comment: Just run the two queries.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
create table table3 as select item from table1; 
alter table table3 add column student TEXT;
update table3 set student = (select student from table2);
```

Comment: Also, use this solution, I think it explains what you want to do.     https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1198124/combine-two-tables-that-have-no-common-fields