# Can a SQL view contains 2 select queries

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to create a view that I need to contain those 2 selects:

```
SELECT * FROM T1 LEFT OUTER JOIN T2 ON T1.`id`=T2.`fieldID` ORDER BY T1.`id` ASC
```

and this one:

```
SELECT 
a.`id`, 
b.`field1`,
c.`field2`,
........ 20 more fields
FROM 
T1 a, `table2` b, `table3` c
WHERE  .... AND .... AND ... an a lot of clauses
```

The T1 from first select is the same from the second select. So first I need to attach to T1 the data from T2 and after that to extend with columns from other tables from the same database. I'm using MySQL
Is there a way to optimize what I have? Thank you in advance!

Comment: _Columns_, not fields...

Comment: Combine how? Show us sample result from each query, and then the combined result. Formatted text please, not images.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Combine two tables that have no common fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1198124/combine-two-tables-that-have-no-common-fields)

Comment: Do you want to combine your first `select` and `second` then product a single set of value ??

Comment: You cannot create a single view that returns multiple results/tables if that is what you are asking.

Comment: @ssn yes thats what I want.

Comment: @BlueDotRo That is not possible - only one resultset for each `view` is allowed.