# I have two tables in MySQL that does not have any relationship and want to show the output side by side

Tags: mysql

Hi I have two tables like the below

1) liability has three columns id, liability_name, liability_amount
2) Asset has three columns id, asset_name, asset_amount

Both of them does not have any relationship (the id is just an auto incremental number). This is for a balance sheet, I want to show the output as below

**Liability Name     Amount          Asset Name        Amount**
Share Capital          100000                Cash on Hand      2345000
Secured Loan        1000000        Cash at Bank          125000
Unsecured Loan        10000

Like that. Also please note there is no relationship between these tables and number of rows may vary from one table to another table.

Is there a way to write a single query in MySQL to produce the above output?

Comment: you have to make the relationship between two tables. If there any chance keep the liability id in your asset table

Comment: In general UNION allows you to combine essentially separate results into one result set.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Combine two tables that have no common fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1198124/combine-two-tables-that-have-no-common-fields)

Answer (score 0):

You can not do with single query due to no relation between tables. You can select both tables at once using following query

```
SELECT * FROM liability , Asset
```

but then output will be repeating as below,

```
Liability Name     Amount          Asset Name        Amount
Share Capital          100000      Cash on Hand      2345000
Secured Loan        1000000        Cash on Hand      2345000
Unsecured Loan        10000        Cash on Hand      2345000
Share Capital          100000      Cash at Bank      125000
Secured Loan        1000000        Cash at Bank      125000
Unsecured Loan        10000        Cash at Bank      125000
```