# Using TSQL how can I create a running total using custom time periods

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sum, left-join

I have two tables as shown in the image below. I would like to build a query that aggregates the count in the Jobs table and shows a running total for each period. I have provided an example of the required output below. Can you please help?

Many thanks

[image]

Comment: Why do you store Period twice? It's not needed in the Jobs table. Keep PeriodID, as a FK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use CTE and then use PARTITION BY to achieve the result.

```sql
DECLARE @periods table(periodid int, periodname char(10))
DECLARE @jobs table(jobid int, periodid int, periodname char(10),cnt int)

INSERT INTO @periods
VALUES (1,'JAN20'),(2,'FEB20'),(3,'MAR20')

INSERT INTO @jobs
VALUES (1234,1,'JAN20',1),(1234,3,'MAR20',2),(9999,2,'FEB20',3);

;WITH CTE_JobPeriod AS
(SELECT j.jobId, p.Periodname, p.periodid
FROM
(SELECT distinct JobID FROM @Jobs) as j
CROSS JOIN 
(SELECT Periodname, PeriodId FROM @Periods) as p
), CTE_JobPeriodCount AS
(
SELECT c.JobId, c.Periodname, c.periodId, j.cnt
FROM CTE_JobPeriod as c
LEFT OUTER JOIN @Jobs AS j
ON j.JobId = c.JobId
AND j.Periodname = c.Periodname
)
SELECT JobId, periodname, 
isnull(SUM(Cnt) over(partition by JobId ORDER BY PeriodId),0) as cnt
FROM CTE_JobPeriodCount
```

```
+-------+------------+-----+
| JobId | periodname | cnt |
+-------+------------+-----+
|  1234 | JAN20      |   1 |
|  1234 | FEB20      |   1 |
|  1234 | MAR20      |   3 |
|  9999 | JAN20      |   0 |
|  9999 | FEB20      |   3 |
|  9999 | MAR20      |   3 |
+-------+------------+-----+
```

Answer (score 2):

You can cross join the periods with the list of jobs, then bring the table with a `left join`, and aggregate:

```
select p.period, j.jobid, coalesce(sum(x.cnt), 0) as cnt
from period p
cross join (select distinct jobid from jobs) j
left join jobs x on x.jobid = j.jobid and x.periodid <= p.period
group by p.periodid, j.jobid
```

`count` is a language keyword, hence not a good choice for a column name; I renamed it to `cnt`.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/8d4c5/10/0)

```sql
SELECT A.Period, A.JobID, (A.Count + ISNULL(J.Count,0)) AS [Count]
FROM (
   SELECT DISTINCT P.PeriodID,J.JOBID, P.Period, 0 AS [Count] FROM Periods AS P, Jobs AS J
) AS A
LEFT JOIN Jobs AS J ON A.PeriodID=J.PeriodID AND A.JobID=J.JobID
ORDER BY A.JobID,A.PeriodID
```

A [cartesian product](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1198234) is used to join the two tables to get every period joined to every job. This is then made distinct, so that each combination of PeriodID and JobID appears only once. Finally, join to Jobs table again to add the counts.